# Clean database after adding dependant: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering how I can clean the database once I add to an attribute `dependant: :destroy`.
For example, I had a Post who has `has_many :comments`. I removed this Post when comments were not `dependant: :destroy` in the Post model. Now they are dependant and I would like to clean the database ie. remove those comments.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I may not have been clear enough : I'm looking for a way to do that over the database without having to do some specific queries but a global one. Something of this format `rake db:clean_my_database`

Answer (score 0):

Run through all you comments and destroy those who have a blank? Post..

```
Comment.all.each { |com| com.destroy if com.post.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Comment.all.each{ |c| c.destroy if c.post.nil? }`